# As Trevor, am I able to store a car in the Vespucci beach safehouse driveway (Floyd's Apartment)?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

As Trevor, am I able to store a car in the Vespucci Beach safehouse driveway (Floyd's Apartment) without it disappearing and I don't ever get the car back?

Comment: I've edited in 'Floyd's Apartment' into your question as this is Trevor's safehouse in Vespucci Beach, which is what I think you're talking about. If this is incorrect, just edit your question.